# baseUrl not being found when running cypress tests through gitlab-ci

Tags: reactjs, gitlab-ci, cypress

I'am newly with giltab-ci and cypress and I trying to verify cypress tests with a gitlab-ci, i currently have as gitlab-ci.yml script :

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  npm_config_cache: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.npm"
  CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/Cypress"

stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  paths:
  - .npm
  - cache/Cypress
  - node_modules

install:
  image: cypress/base:12.16.1
  stage: build
  script:
  - npm ci
  - $(npm bin)/cypress cache path
  - $(npm bin)/cypress cache list
  - $(npm bin)/cypress verify

cypress-e2e:
  stage: test
  image: cypress/base:12.16.1
  script:
  - $(npm bin)/cypress run

  artifacts:
    paths:
    - cypress/screenshots
    - cypress/videos
    expire_in: 1 day

test:e2e:
  stage: test
  image: cypress/browsers:chrome67
  script:
  - $(npm bin)/cypress run --browser chrome
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - cypress/screenshots
    - cypress/videos
    expire_in: 1 day
```

ans as i have as cypress.json :

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

Unfortunately, gitlab pipeline throws the below error, when it attempts to run my Cypress tests:

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:
   > http://localhost:3000
 We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.
 Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.
 We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
 We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
 We will try connecting to it 1 more time...
 Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.
 Please start this server and then run Cypress again.
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI the error message is different `Please start this server and then run Cypress again`. The problem is - you run your tests without running your App inside the docker! So you need to re-configure your *.yml file and add command according to your way of how you run your application e.g. `npm start`